# libssl not found by Python on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, libssl, ubuntu-22.04

As the title says, I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and my previously working setup now says `ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when starting Jupyter, and equivalently throws `Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/jupyter/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/jupyter/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping` whenever trying to use `pip`.

Libssl is actually available at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1`. I could change LD_LIBRARY_PATH but this seems to be a workaround.

Comment: @furas the error is clear: libssl is not seen by python. This happens when trying to `import ssl`, in any context.

Comment: but full error may show other information which can be useful for us but you can think they are useless.

Comment: `libssl1.0.0 → libssl.so.1.1` was earlier Ubuntu´s. **22.04** has `libssl3 → libssl.so.3` : https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libssl3 → → https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libssl3/filelist

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by reinstalling the environment.

I use `pipenv` and `pyenv`. I removed the `pipenv` environment and the Python version using `pyenv`. Then reinstalled both.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might work. I currently cannot try due to a bad internet connection (torch is heavy). But will try asap.

Comment: Also check if the SO python interpreter works as expected. If it is broken, you will need to reinstall the base python from scratch. Good luck!